# check how many variables are stored in a variable

Tags: bash

i would like to know how would you find how many variables are stored in a variable..for example:

```
dir=$(ls)
```

dir would store the names of all the files in the directory and i know you can cycle through them with a while-do loop. but is there a way for me to know how many variables (file names in this case) are stored in the variable (dir)?

thanks

Comment: I think technically there's only one variable (`dir`), and it's just a long string. If you _assume_ the entries are space-delimited (not the case where fields can have spaces), and you're asking how many space-delimited strings are in a variable, then you should reframe the question that way. :)

Comment: You should not use `($(ls))` as the accepted answer suggests because it does not handle files with spaces in their names correctly. i.e. your array count will be larger than the actual number of files. Instead you should accept [Glenn's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8750198/207248) using `$(*)` which not only handles files with spaces correctly, but it also doesn't need to fork off an external process to call `ls`.

Comment: @SiegeX - Since the accepted answers the original question (how to 'count'), it would be fair to edit that flaw, yes? I am doing so now. So +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean way would be to use bash arrays.

```
dir=($(ls))
```

EDIT: The above does not handle spaces properly, see Glenn's answer for the correct way, which still creates a bash array:

```
dir=(*)
```

Notice the additional braces above. i.e. I declared dir to be an array, rather than a single variable.

Then you can simply get the number of elements in dir (the array):

```
echo ${#dir[@]}
```

You can access the individual elements:

```
echo ${dir[0]}
echo ${dir[5]}
```

More details here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: can you please explain the "[@]" and what it does?

Comment: @czchlong: Quoting the link I refer to at the bottom:
"either ${array_name[@]} or ${array_name[*]} refers to all the elements of the array". So I guess the # is an operator that counts.

Answer (score 5):

with bash, this is a more reliable way to collect the contents of the directory into an array

```
dir=(*)
```

That will handle elements with spaces properly.

Comment: +1 for correcting how the array should be formed in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | wc -l
```

or

```
echo "$dir" | wc -l
```

gives you an approximation. (It doesn't work well when filenames contain newlines.)

The reliable way to find out the number of files in a directory is

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | tr '\n\0' '_\n' | wc -l
```

but that includes the hidden files, which `ls` doesn't list by default.

Comment: @iLate: but not for filenames containing newlines.

Comment: `echo "$dir" | wc -l` 
Caution: `dir=$(ls)` will split filenames containing newline character...
@larsmans You was faster ;-)

Comment: +a lot! Don't parse `ls` output!

Answer (score 0):

A Bash variable is a string or an array of strings, nothing else. To check how many *words* are stored in a string variable:

```
$ echo "foo bar baz" | wc -w
3
```

To figure out how many files exist in the *current directory*, @glenn has the right idea. To figure out how many files exist matching an *arbitrary `find` command*, just use this:

```
$ find [your options] -printf x | wc -c
```